# Argument in message expression is an uninitialized value?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, sharekit, analyzer

I get the warning Argument in message expression is an uninitialized value in the bolded line below:

```
***SHKActionSheet *as = [[SHKActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"Share")***
                                                      delegate:as
                                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
    as.item = [[[SHKItem alloc] init] autorelease];
    as.item.shareType = type;
```

Any ideas whats wrong or how I can fix it?
P.S - This is in ShareKit

Thanks!

Edit1: So you're saying to do this?

```
+ (SHKActionSheet *)actionSheetForType:(SHKShareType)type
{
    SHKItem *myItem = [SHKItem text:@"Share"];  // See SHKItem for other convenience constructors for URL, image, text and file item types.
    SHKActionSheet *as = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:myItem];
    as.item.shareType = type;

    as.sharers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    NSArray *favoriteSharers = [SHK favoriteSharersForType:type];

    // Add buttons for each favorite sharer
    id class;
    for(NSString *sharerId in favoriteSharers)
    {
        class = NSClassFromString(sharerId);
        if ([class canShare])
        {
            [as addButtonWithTitle: [class sharerTitle] ];
            [as.sharers addObject:sharerId];
        }
    }

    // Add More button
    [as addButtonWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"More...")];

    // Add Cancel button
    [as addButtonWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"Cancel")];
    as.cancelButtonIndex = as.numberOfButtons -1;

    return [as autorelease];
}
```

Edit2:

```
+ (SHKActionSheet *)actionSheetForType:(SHKShareType)type
{

    SHKActionSheet *as = [[SHKActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"Share")
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
    as.item = [[[SHKItem alloc] init] autorelease];
    as.delegate = self;


    as.item.shareType = type;

    as.sharers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    NSArray *favoriteSharers = [SHK favoriteSharersForType:type];

    // Add buttons for each favorite sharer
    id class;
    for(NSString *sharerId in favoriteSharers)
    {
        class = NSClassFromString(sharerId);
        if ([class canShare])
        {
            [as addButtonWithTitle: [class sharerTitle] ];
            [as.sharers addObject:sharerId];
        }
    }

    // Add More button
    [as addButtonWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"More...")];

    // Add Cancel button
    [as addButtonWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"Cancel")];
    as.cancelButtonIndex = as.numberOfButtons -1;

    return [as autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is on this line:

```
delegate:as
```

the problem is you are setting delegate to 'as' which is the name of the action sheet you are in the process of initialising.  (so you are trying to pass a ref to an object you are in the process of initialising as an argument to its initialiser).

Instead set the delegate to nil on the alloc/init call and explicitly set the delegate after the call.

```
SHKActionSheet *as = [[SHKActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"Share")***
                                    delegate:nil
                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
as.delegate = as;
as.item = [[[SHKItem alloc] init] autorelease];
as.item.shareType = type;
```

Comment: If I do delegate:self I get a real warning: Incompatible pointer types sending 'Class' to parameter of type id <UIActionSheetDelegate>

Comment: You would need to implement the UIActionSheetDelegate methods in your class.  I just had a look at the SHKActionSheet object - it does actually implement the UIActionSheetDelegate protocol so it would not be illogical to set it as a delegate for itself. I'll add another answer about using the static convenience methods (so I can format the code)

Comment: Check my edit1 above and please confirm if that is what I should do or not. Thanks! :D

Comment: Also it shows a analyzer warning on the last line return [as autorelease]; and the warning is: autorelease too many times, how would I fix this?

Comment: Sorry I'm getting a bit confused as to what you are trying to do. Are you trying to use SHKActionSheet, or trying to modify the SHK code library. If you are trying to use an SHKActionSheet - just use the convenience methods somewhere in your own code as I've shown in my edit.  If you are trying to modify the SHK library code itself (which in your edited example above you are actually placing the code inside the SHKActionSheet class) then you'd need to elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Im trying to modify the SHK code library. This is in the SHKActionSheet.m. There was a warning in there that I am trying to fix, I am trying to achieve the same functionality but just fix the warning.

Comment: Ok to fix the warning - try setting delegate:nil on the alloc/init call, then after the alloc/init call explicitly set as.delegate = as;  I'll edit my original answer to this.

Comment: It still shows the warning with Edit2 in my original post. Any ideas?

Comment: in edit 2 you have as.delegate = self  - make it as.delegate = as; self has no value in a static method.